# how to use road speed per request in graphhopper routing

Tags: graphhopper

As per the graphhopper 0.9 release, it says

*A new graph change API to change road speed and access properties, #845. Can be applied before preprocessing or per-request.*

how do i use it, can someone point me to the documentation with example ?

thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is no good documentation at the moment. Have a look into the [tests](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.9/web/src/test/java/com/graphhopper/http/ChangeGraphServletIT.java#L81):

1. Disable speed mode - set `prepare.ch.weightings=no` in the config.properties
2. Create a GeoJSON where e.g. you want to change the access properties to false (blocking):

   ```
   {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [1.521692, 42.522969]
          },
          "properties": {
            "vehicles": ["car"],
            "access": false
           }
        }]
   }
   ```
3. Then POST this as json to the `/change` endpoint.

Please note that in 0.9.0

- for geometry `type` only Point, MultiPoint and LineString are supported.
- for the properties only `access` (Boolean) and `speed` (Double) are supported that can be applied to multiple vehicles (but only in both directions).

You can also use [the Java equivalent](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.9/reader-json/src/test/java/com/graphhopper/storage/change/ChangeGraphHelperTest.java#L69).

Please see [this issue](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/1133) to improve the documentation.

Comment: i am getting below response \n {
  "message" : "Not found"
} <br>  i am using the configuration as below <br>

Comment: i am getting response {
  "message" : "Not found"
}   i am using the configuration as prepare.ch.weightings=no, prepare.lm.weightings=fastest

Comment: The change endpoint is disabled by default, enable it by `web.change_graph.enabled=true`. Please review also this topic - https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-use-road-speed-per-request-in-graphhopper-routing/2267